# Trying to make radio buttons with using Streambuilder and Bloc in Flutter. but don't work

Tags: radio-button, flutter

I tried to make radiobuttons by using Streambuilder and Bloc.

so I made streamcontroler and when radiobuttons clicked,

I  made streamcontrl.add(value) implemented,  but Streambuilder don't listen

that stream. I tested onchanged value of radio. and

Please figure out what's wrong with it.

This is full code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main(){
   runApp(new MaterialApp(
  home: new MyApp(),
 ));
 }


 class bloc {

  StreamController <int> ctrl = StreamController() ;
  get blocvalue => ctrl.stream;   
  void setvalue (value ) {
       ctrl.sink.add(value) ; }
 }

 class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => new _State();
  }

 class _State extends State<MyApp>{



 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text('Name here'),
    ),

    body: new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: new Center(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder(
              stream: bloc().blocvalue,
              initialData: 0,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot <int> snapshot) 
       {
                List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();
                for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                  list.add(new RadioListTile(
                    value: i,
                    groupValue: snapshot.data,
                    onChanged: bloc().setvalue,
                    activeColor: Colors.green,
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                    title: new Text('Item: ${i}'),
                    dense: true,
                    //    subtitle: new Text('sub title'),
                  ));

                }
                return Column(children: list,); })
         ],
        ),
      ),
     ),
    );
   }
   }
```

Comment: yes, you re right,  I added print (snapshot.data). I could get only 0 of initialData of Streambuilder.

Comment: you are creating a new `bloc()` inside `build()` method, thats why - simply create it once as a filed of `_State` class

Comment: Thanks. I solved this problem with your comment.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: Hi @AlexMoon, I am in same problem. Can you pease show me updated code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by pksink in the comments, you're creating a new bloc inside build by calling setting it in StreamBuilder as `bloc().blocValue`. What you can do here is declare it as `final myBloc = bloc();` outside of the `bloc` and set it on your StreamBuilder as `myBloc.blocValue`. With this, a new instance of bloc won't be created with every rebuild of Widget build.